# How do I listen for an async response while doing invokeMethod()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a small flutter app where I use a native library for some computation. The communication is two-way between dart and java (on android) and uses methodChannels for this. 
I call await in_channel.invokeMethod("someJavaMethod") from dart to start the computation. This triggers an init of the native library from Java. The result from this init is coming back as an async JNI call which then triggers out_channel.invokeMethod("someDartMethod").

My plan was to bind the out_channel to a local dart broadcast stream such that I could invoke someJavaMethod and then just await myMethodStream.where((m) => m.method == "someDartMethod")...

Problem is that the "someDartMethod" can come before the "someJavaMethod" call invocation has returned.

combined code example of what I have:

```
    static const MethodChannel _channel_in = const 
    MethodChannel('native_lib_wrapper_out'); 
    static const MethodChannel _channel_out = const 
    MethodChannel('native_lib_wrapper_in');
    final StreamController<MethodCall> _methodStreamController = new 
    StreamController.broadcast();

    NativeLibWrapper._() {
          _channel_in.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) {
              _methodStreamController.add(call);
              return;
         });
    }


    Future<Map<dynamic,dynamic>> initLib(String id, String filePath) 
      async {
        Map<dynamic,dynamic> ret;

        ret = await _channel_out.invokeMethod("initLib",  <String, 
        dynamic> { // data to be passed to the function
                    'id': id,
                    'filePath': filePath,
                  });
        print('initLib - invokeMethod done. wait for stream');
        if(ret["status"] == 0) {
          await NativeLibWrapper.instance._methodStream
                .where((m) => m.method == "libInitEnded")
                .map((m){
                    var args = m.arguments;
                    ret = args;
                  }).first;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

I would have expected the code to get the method call libInitEnded on my stream and then it should return after that point but it continuously hangs in the await on the stream and from the logs it looks like the libInitEnded is called before the print in the middle.

So is there a better way to structure this? it will not be the only methods going back and forth so I hope to get a good stable solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*One channel*

You should only need *one* channel. No need for in and out channels. Both ends may invoke operations on the other over the one channel.

*There's only one UI thread*

When you call from Dart to Native, the native method is handled by the native UI thread. Unless you are using a thread pool, that means that Dart to Native methods are handled in order. There's no point in *not* `await`ing the answer of every native method. Or, in other words, there's no point in launching two native methods at the same time, since they will be executed consecutively by the single native thread. (Note that you should not perform time-consuming operations on the native thread, as this will interfere with other things it does like gesture detection.) Every Dart to native method should return its result.

*Using a thread pool*

If the single thread / single method call at a time is unacceptable, consider a thread pool at the native end. Now you can have multiple methods in flight, since there are multiple threads of execution. Now you should design your call/response like you might for communication with a server over a socket. The client gives each request an "invoke id". Each method simply returns a boolean that the request was queued. On completion of the request, the other end invokes the 'done' method, passing the original id and the result. The caller can then match up the response id with the request id and handle the response appropriately (and cancel any timer started to detect timeout). Note that responses can then arrive in any order, but are matched with their request by id.

On Android, you must invoke native to Dart methods on the `UIThread`. If you are calling the 'done' method from a worker thread you need to `post` a `Runnable` lambda to the main looper.

Comment: The thread pool mentioned is what I want to achieve in the end with this solution but actually the last paragraph was the one solving the problem. Turns out the native to dart method invocation was called but never executed as it was not in UI thread. Simply putting it in on UI thread solved the problem and my initial code worked as expected. Thanks for a very thorough answer. .

Comment: a link to the technique using the thread pool would be very useful, a small example would be best

Comment: I think the question was actually about how to call async Java code from Dart across a `MethodChannel`. I have the same question. The `MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler.onMethodCall` method requires a result to be returned synchronously. If the Android method you want to call takes an async callback, how do you take the async result and pass it back as the result of `onMethodCall`, given that Java doesn't have `async`/`await` or some other way to yield and wait for a callback to be called?

Comment: @LukeHutchison Actually, you don't need to provide a sync result. (I used to think like you that you had to, but no.) Notice how you don't actually `return` anything from the handler. Instead you typically call `result.success(something)`. It's perfectly OK to hold onto `result` and call `result.whatever()` later - as long as you do it on the main thread. If your callback is a lambda, you don't even have to do anything special - the compiler will keep `result` in scope.

Comment: In the original answer, the thread pool idea is over engineered and unnecessary! Under the hood the method channel is already giving each method invocation a reference that allows it to tie the request up with the response. That's why calling `result.whatever()` later works - `result` has stored that request number and when it sends the response back to Dart, the Dart end knows (from that id) which request's future to complete.

Comment: @RichardHeap you are correct, I finally figured that out, after filing a bug against Android asking for async method call support, which was promptly closed as invalid! You are right, the `result` object can be passed anywhere, and whenever you're ready to return a result, you just call `result.success`. Pro-tip: you should never call blocking methods from `MethodCallHandler.onMethodCall` (or anything it calls), because you will block the UI thread. Instead, run the blocking method on another thread, and pass the result object to it.